# Replace string on a line using sed command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have following content in a file

```
return o.baseUrl="http://info.example.com/api/v1/",a.init=t,o.login=e(o.baseUrl+"login",{email:"@email",password:"@password"}
```

I want to replace `info.example.com` with `api.example.com`

Currently I am using

```
sed -i "s/^info\.example\.com.*$/api.example.com/g" /var/html/www/index.js
```

But this is not working. 
I don't know much about regular expression. 
Can somebody help me on this ?

Comment: Drop `^` and `.*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` anchor matches `info\.example\.com` at the beginning of the lines.

Anchors are useless in your case. Remove the `^` and `$` from your pattern:

```
sed -i 's/info\.example\.com/api.example.com/g' /var/html/www/index.js
```

More about anchors [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/re.html#tag_007_003_008).

Answer (score 1):

In `sed` you can provide exact expression to be replaced.

```
sed 's/info\.example.com/api.example.com/g' file
```